# Javascript: Math.round() per 0.25?

Tags: javascript

I would like to round numbers to the nearest 0.25-value like this:

```
2.1 -> 2
2.2 -> 2.25
3.4 -> 3.5
5.6 -> 5.5
9.8 -> 9.75
9.9 -> 10
```

Is this possible in javascript?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply the number by `4`, round it, and divide by 4:

```js
[2.1, 2.2, 3.4, 5.6, 9.8, 9.8, 9.9].forEach(
  num => console.log(Math.round(num * 4) / 4)
);
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Also, now it seems this was asked before. I searched before asking but did not find what I was looking for back then.